# phpMyAdmin: Token mismatch but only in Safari

Tags: safari, phpmyadmin, token, mismatch

For ages running phpmyadmin 3.4 I was getting a "token mismatch" error in Safari (my primary browser) when doing various random tasks in phpmyadmin.

I've just upgraded to 4.0.9 and I'm still getting the same problem.  Firefox is absolutely fine.  I've tried clearing all cookies in Safari relating to this server, but still the same problem.

Can anybody suggest why this might be happening only on Safari, or steps I can take to narrow down the cause?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ed Ludlow

Comment: Just to confirm: working with phpMyAdmin and Safari is a true hell. If it's not the dreaded Token mismatch error, then something else goes wrong, usually after a phpMyAdmin update.

Comment: What Safari version? You may also wish to follow this bug ticket with the same issue https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4438/

Comment: i have same problem too with safari.... anybody knows what is problem answer ?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution for solve this problem;

this solution was for phpmyadmin 3.1.5 but worked for me on phpmyadmin 4.4.11.

solution :

in `config.inc.php` file enable this:

```
$cfg['AllowThirdPartyFraming'] = true;
```

for more info : 
[link](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3523499&group_id=23067&%20atid=377408)